# sd_journal_send to send binary data. How can I retrieve the data using journalctl?

Tags: c++, linux, binary, systemd, systemd-journald

I'm looking at systemd-journal as a method of collecting logs from external processors. I'm very interested in it's ability to collect binary data when necessary.

I'm simply testing and investigating journal right now. I'm well aware there are other, probably better, solutions.

I'm logging binary data like so:

```
// strData is a string container containing binary data
strData += '\0';

sd_journal_send(
    "MESSAGE=test_msg",
    "MESSAGE_ID=12345",
    "BINARY=%s", strData.c_str(),
    NULL);
```

The log line shows up when using the `journalctl` tool. I can find the log line like this from the terminal:

`journalctl MESSAGE_ID=12345`

I can get the binary data of all logs in journal like so from the terminal:

`journalctl --field=BINARY`

I need to get the binary data to a file so that I can access from a program and decode it. How can I do this?

This does not work:

`journalctl --field=BINARY MESSAGE_ID=12345`

I get there error:

"Extraneous arguments starting with 'MESSAGE_ID=1234567890987654321"

Any suggestions? The documentation on systemd-journal seems slim. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You just got the wrong option. See the docs for:

> ```
>    -F, --field=
>        Print all possible data values the specified field can take in all entries of the journal.
> ```

vs

> ```
>    --output-fields=
>        A comma separated list of the fields which should be included in the output.
> ```

You also have to specify the plain output format (`-o cat`) to get the raw content:

```
journalctl  --output-fields=BINARY  MESSAGE_ID=12345  -o cat
```

Comment: I'm running 16.04.4 Ubuntu, and it seems like I have systemd 229 installed. 229 doesn't seem to support --output-field. I'm looking to figure out how to upgrade now.